# Trying to print the center position of a square

Tags: python, opencv

I have tried to use cv2.putText and it appears to show the position based on the the top right of the window and not the actual center of the image. It will probably be an obvious fix since I just started using opencv

```
import os
import numpy as np

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
  

org = (50, 50)
fontScale = 1
color = (255, 0, 0)
  
radius = 3
thickness = 2
cascPath=os.path.dirname(cv2.__file__)+"/data/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)



video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while (True):


    
    ret, frames = video_capture.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frames, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
            gray,
            scaleFactor=1.1,
            minNeighbors=5,
            minSize=(30, 30),
            flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
        )
        
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:


        cv2.rectangle(frames, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        text = (x+w//2), (y+h//2) 
        
        cv2.circle(frames, (cx, cy), radius, (255, 0, 0), -1)
        cv2.putText(frames, str(text), org, font, fontScale, color, thickness)






        
    cv2.imshow('Video', frames)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break   


video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: HI, you have to change the put text position, right ? I can't understand what's the problem, can you please elaborate it

Comment: I need to use putText to display the position of the rectangle around the face, in relation to the center of the screen, but when I use the code I put in the post, it shows it in relation to the top right corner. I need to probably change either the putText or the Text variable

Comment: @Idontknoww1234. You cannot use org . You have to specified x and y derived from rectangle.  Try this: (x - 10, y - 10). You need to change x,y axis.

Comment: org is the position of the text, not the actual text

Comment: please show us what your program shows you -- why do you calculate the center of the rectangle, but then only put that info into `text`, which isn't text but a tuple? you need to pass that as `org=...` . did you notice, you set `org` once and never again?

Comment: @Idontknoww1234. Do you want text to be centre of window, but not centre of rectangle?  I used same code as your

Answer (score 0):

With the cv2.getTextSize() function, you can calculate the pixel size of the text you will put and subtract it from the text's position. In this way, the text will be right on the center.

```
text = (x+w//2), (y+h//2)

text_size,t = cv2.getTextSize(text=str(text), fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, fontScale=1, thickness=1)
text_size_x,text_size_y = text_size

text_pos =  (x+w//2)-(text_size_x//2), (y+h//2)+(text_size_y//2)
```

Here is a working code

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
  

org = (50, 50)
fontScale = 1
color = (255, 0, 0)
  
radius = 3
thickness = 2
cascPath=os.path.dirname(cv2.__file__)+"/data/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)



video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while (True):


    
    ret, frames = video_capture.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frames, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
            gray,
            scaleFactor=1.1,
            minNeighbors=5,
            minSize=(30, 30),
            flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
        )

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:


        cv2.rectangle(frames, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        text = (x+w//2), (y+h//2)

        text_size,t = cv2.getTextSize(text=str(text), fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, fontScale=1, thickness=1)
        text_size_x,text_size_y = text_size

        text_pos =  (x+w//2)-(text_size_x//2), (y+h//2)+(text_size_y//2)

        #cv2.circle(frames, (cx, cy), radius, (255, 0, 0), -1)
        cv2.putText(frames, str(text), text_pos, font, fontScale, color, thickness)

    cv2.imshow('Video', frames)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break   


video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: The problem isn't the text position, its the actual text, it isnt considering the center of the window as the actual center and for some reason its using the top left corner, so in the position that would be the center of the window, it shows something like (450, 400)